# Getting Color and Depth Frames from Kinect Version 2 Simultaneously in C++

Tags: c++, image, kinect, kinect-sdk

I am trying to extract Color & Depth Frames from the New Kinect (Kinect Version 2) using the Kinect for Windows 2 SDK.

I am trying to do this by using the below API Call:

```
OpenMultiSourceFrameReader(FrameSourceTypes_Color | FrameSourceTypes_Depth , &m_multisource_reader))
```

However, using this I am unable to get both the Color and Depth frames simultaneously from the Kinect (Only Depth frames are received at a time).

**How do we get the Frames simultaneously from the Kinect ? Is there any other approach ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this issue , Apparently we have to write two seperate threads to pull the Color Frames and Depth frames (I was Trying to pull the frames in a single call itself).

Answer (score 0):

You can also check [MultiSourceFrameArrived](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowspreview.kinect.multisourceframereader.multisourceframearrived.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1) event - it carries Color and Depth frames simultaneously. Be careful though - they might not be filled at all times (their reference might be set to *null* in some events). If you want perfect synchronization - ignore all frames where both or either one of them is set to null. However, generally, that is not necessary, and buffering the last non-null frame is enough until a missing one arrives.